# Can I find Logical Children by Type

Tags: c#, wpf

I know i can use `LogicalTreeHelper` class to find children node for every element searching it by name. But is there a possibility to find a child node by Type? For example, what if i would like to find a ListBox element in my Window without knowing its Name property??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a built in way of doing this. Probably the best approach would be to recursively call `LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren()` until a child control of the specified type is found.

Answer (score 1):

Note that descending the Logical tree cleanly is actually a little tricky, here's a nice [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfElementTrees.aspx) on the intricacies of both the visual and logical trees.

I don't think any helper code exists to do this for you so implementing a recursive walk over the tree is required.